# How find nodejs forever patch?

Tags: node.js, forever

I install forever extension for nodejs and forever work without any problem, but i can not find forever patch for crontab. He must be in /usr/local/bin/forever  http://prntscr.com/9jo8pr but there empty. Why?

Comment: what's the output of `which forever` (I assume it is installed globally)? Otherwise, if you installed locally, it is in `./node_modules/forever/bin/forever`

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just explicitly write "forever" and all work.

```
@reboot forever start /home/dimonchik/profile/wp_users_update.js
```